# Register form insert the record with "sorry,email is exist" aleart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

in my register form i want  to validate the user input and check if the email is exist or not in the data base , the php insert the value if the email not exist in db but it still give me the "sorry,email is exist" alert and not enter to profile.html should i add after insert a select query?

```
 $('#sign-up').live('pageshow', function() {
        // Declare editMode : true when a user is logged in , false otherwise
        var editMode = globals.currentUser != null;

    if(editMode) {
        $("#txt-first-name").val(globals.currentUser.firstName);
        $("#txt-last-name").val(globals.currentUser.lastName);
        $("#txt-email").val(globals.currentUser.email);
    }

    $("#btn-submit").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var firstName = $("#txt-first-name").val();
        if(!firstName || firstName == "") {
            alert("enter first name");
            $("#txt-first-name").focus();
            return;
        }

        var lastName = $("#txt-last-name").val();
        if(!lastName || lastName == "") {
            alert("enter last name");
            $("#txt-last-name").focus();
            return;
        }

        var email = $("#txt-email").val();
        var filter = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  

        if(!email || email == ""|| !filter.test(email)) {
            alert("enter correct email");
            $("#txt-email").focus();
            return;
        }

        var password = $("#txt-password").val();
        if(!editMode && (!password || password == "")) {
            alert("enter password");
            $("#txt-password").focus();
            return;
        }

        if(password.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
            alert("password must not have space");
            $("#txt-password").focus();
            return;
        }

        var passwordConfirm = $("#txt-password-confirm").val();
        if(!editMode && (!passwordConfirm || passwordConfirm == "")) {
            alert("confirm password");
            $("#txt-password-confirm").focus();
            return;
        }

        // Check if password and password confirmation are equal
        if(passwordConfirm !== password) {
            alert("passwords not equal to each other");
            $("#txt-password-confirm").focus();
            return;
        }

        var data = {
            email: email,
            password: password == "" ? "" : btoa(password),
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            id: (globals.currentUser != null ? globals.currentUser.userid : null)
        };

        $.getJSON(globals.serviceHost + (editMode ? "editprofile.php" : "register.php"), data,
        // on success callback
        function (result) {
            console.log("result : ");
            console.log(result);
            if(editMode) {
                globals.currentUser.firstName = firstName;
                globals.currentUser.lastName = lastName;
                globals.currentUser.email = email;
                alert("information has been edited");
                window.history.back();
            }

             if(!result.user || result.user == "data") {
                alert("sorry,email is exist");
                $("#txt-email").focus();
                return;

            } 


                globals.currentUser = result.user;
                alert("register successfully ");
                $.mobile.navigate("profile.html");

        });

    });
});
```

//php

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $firstName = $_GET['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_GET['lastName'];
    $data=array();

            $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' ");

        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($q);
        if($num_rows == 0){

        $qr = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstName, lastName) VALUES ('$email', '$password', '$firstName', '$lastName') ");

            echo '{"inserted":"true"}';

        }
        else {
            $data = "data";
            echo '{"user":'. json_encode($data) .'}'; 
        }


?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you NEED to fix this.

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: Hi @RaomB, looks like the cause is `!result.user`, since you wont have that user data in the json sent back to you whenever the user is successfully inserted into db. also, @Enstage is correct, at least [make a proper prepared statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Comment: The GET arrays' origins are unknown. The HTML for this needs to be added. Look at your developer console, use php's error reporting and error checking on the queries.

Comment: and not just the injection but passwords in plain text.

Comment: @RaomB for example: the user defines the `$_GET['email']` variable, if I entered `random@email.com'; DROP *; --` then your query would end up being `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='random@email.com'; DROP *; --' `. Needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition

```
 if(!result.user || result.user == "data")
```

always return true because is always true based on your responses

Users does not exist:

```
 echo '{"inserted":"true"}';
```

User exists:

```
 $data = "data";
 echo '{"user":'. json_encode($data) .'}';
```

Your condition should be something like

```
if(result.user == "data")
```